# Multiply list elements by two or every element by (itself - 1)

Tags: haskell

i need to write a function, which takes positive integers list. If list begins with 2, then every element must be multiplied by 2, in other cases every integer n is written n-1 times.

`two :: [Int] -> [Int]`

i.e:

`two [2,1] ==> [4,2]`

`two [3,2,4] ==> [3,3,2,4,4,4]`

```
multiplyEveryoneByTwo :: [Int] -> [Int]
multiplyEveryoneByTwo [] = []
multiplyEveryoneByTwo [x] = [x*2]
multiplyEveryoneByTwo (x:xs) = (x*2) : multiplyEveryoneByTwo xs

replicateEveryone :: [Int] -> [Int]
replicateEveryone [] = []
replicateEveryone [x] = replicate (x-1) x
replicateEveryone (x:xs) = (replicate (x-1) x) ++ replicateEveryone xs

two :: [Int] -> [Int]
two [x] = if x == 2 then [x*2] else replicate (x-1) x
two (x:xs)
    | x == 2 = multiplyEveryoneByTwo (x:xs) 
    | otherwise = replicateEveryone (x:xs)
```

I'm stuck now with writing that: if my first element of the list is 2, then recursively multiply every element by 2. I tried to do with extra function `multiplyByTwo` but it doesn't work.
The else statement is that i need to replicate every element of the list by (itself - 1)

is it correct approach to pass (x:xs) to my helper functions in here `| x == 2 = multiplyEveryoneByTwo (x:xs)` `| otherwise = replicateEveryone (x:xs)`

Comment: It's recommended that every distinct question be its own entity. Rewriting a question in-place via editing is not as good: the question and the proposed answers get out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest separating your problems into two separate functions

```
multiplyEveryoneByTwo :: [Int] -> [Int]
multiplyEveryoneByTwo ...

replicateEveryone :: [Int] -> [Int]
replicateEveryone ...
```

After you have these two functions tested and working you can create your weird function that combines them

```
weirdf [] = ...
weirdf (x:xs)
   | x == 2 = multiplyEveryone (...)
   |otherwise = replicateEveryone (...)
```

Comment: hello, look at my edit now.. the line `x == 2 = multiplyEveryoneByTwo x` instead of passing x which is head of my list, i need to pass the list, but what is the list symbol ? as you see, I have declared input parameter as (x:xs)

Comment: You can either 1) Rebuild the list by consing the x and the xs inside again 2) Use an `@` pattern `xxs@(x:xs)` to bind the whole name or 3) Not use pattern matching directly in the arguments list and do the case statement / if-then-else inside afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer (since your question was tagged as [homework]), but be careful with your function types. Note the following types:

```
two :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

but multiplyByTwo probably has a type like

```
multiplyByTwo :: Int -> Int
```

Therefore, you have a typing error when you write

```
two (x:xs) = if ... then multiplyByTwo x else ...
```

The type of the **if-then-else** expression must match the return type of **two**. Also, check the types of the two branches (the **then** and the **else**): do they return an expression of the same type? If not, you have another type error.

Comment: hello. i did it, but i'm not sure if it is right approach. i pass (x:xs) to my multiplyEveryoneByTwo function, you will see in my edit
`| x == 2 = multiplyEveryoneByTwo (x:xs)`
`| otherwise = replicateEveryone (x:xs)`

Comment: I don't understand if you still have a question :) Basically, like **missingno** said, you have to notice there are two different functions: "multiply everyone by 2" and "replicate everyone by itself". The general approach is to make sure you understand how to implement each function separately, and then combine them.

Comment: This line is probably unneeded: `two [x] = if x == 2 then [x*2] else replicate (x-1) x`. Think about it, why do you think you need to handle this case separately? Instead, you may be missing another case: what happens when you write `two []`?